# Unable to install package UnmanagedExports

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

In the NuGet Package Manager Console in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8, I hit

```
PM > Install-Package UnmanagedExports
```

I get the following error :

```
Installing 'UnmanagedExports 1.2.7'.
Successfully installed 'UnmanagedExports 1.2.7'.
Adding 'UnmanagedExports 1.2.7' to JNAExample.
Uninstalling 'UnmanagedExports 1.2.7'.
Successfully uninstalled 'UnmanagedExports 1.2.7'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'UnmanagedExports 1.2.7'. 
You are trying to install this package into a project that
targets'.NETCore,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any 
assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
framework. For more information, contact the package author.
    At line:1 char:1
    + Install-Package UnmanagedExports
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo : 
                  NotSpecified: (:[InstallPackage],InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
NuGetCmdletUnhandledExceptionNuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I created a New Project under Visual C# as Class Library.

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Are you really using VS2012?

Comment: Yes I am using VS 2012.

Answer (score 0):

The UnmanagedExports NuGet package has an assembly in the lib/net folder inside the NuGet package. Which means it supports projects that target the full .NET Framework, any version. So it does not support UWP projects.

You would need to find another NuGet package, or find the source, if it is available, and compile that in a UWP project or a project that is compatible.